# Establishing finite expectations for certain sums of iid random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, convex-analysis

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \to [0,+\infty)$ is convex, continuous, and satisfies the property that $\lim_{|x|\to+\infty} f(x) = +\infty$. If needed, we may assume without loss of generaltiy that $f(0)=0$. Let $Y$ be a nonnegative random variable with $\mathbb{E}[Y]<+\infty$, and suppose
$$
F(x) := \mathbb{E}[f(x-Y)] <+\infty
$$
for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$. It can easily be shown that $F$ is convex, continuous, and satisfies the same limit property as $f$ itself.

I want to understand whether the expectation $\mathbb{E}[F(x-Y)]$ is itself finite for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$. This seems intuitively plausible but positive proof seems elusive to me.

Some thoughts:

- If the answer to the above question is positive, then we get the following fact by induction: Letting $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ be iid distributed like $Y$, it would follow that
  $$
  \mathbb{E}[f(x-\sum_{j=1}^{n} Y_j)]<+\infty
  $$
  for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
- In view of the above, one possible direction is to use the inequality
  $$
  f(x-Y_1 - Y_2) \leq \frac{1}{2}[f(x-2Y_1)+f(x-2Y_2)]
  $$
  which follows from the convexity of $f$. It therefore would suffice to show that $\mathbb{E}[f(x-2Y)]$ is finite, which again seems plausible.
- Upon later consideration, this convex inequality does not help us. Consider $f(x) = \exp(|x|)$ and $Y,Y_1,Y_2 \sim \mathrm{Exponential}(2)$ (iid). Then one can show that $\mathbb{E}f(x-Y) < +\infty$ and $\mathbb{E}f(x-Y_1-Y_2)]<+\infty$ while $\mathbb{E}f(x-2Y) = +\infty$ for all $x$. So the previous bullet point is not helpful. Apparently, independence is doing a lot of heavy lifting here.

Any comments would be appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't $Y=2 \mathrm{Exponential}(2)$ satisfy $\mathbb{E}[Y]<+\infty$ and therefore you have found a counterexample?

Comment: I don't think this is enough. Say $U \sim \mathrm{Exponential}(2)$, so $P(Y \leq y) = P(U \leq y/2) = 1 - e^{-y}$, so in fact $Y \sim \mathrm{Exponential}(1)$. But in the case $f(x) = \exp(|x|)$, it would follow that $\mathbb{E} \exp(|x-Y|) = +\infty$ for each $x$, against our assumption.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry I missed that.